# query takes 7 positional arguments but eight were given

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shepard\Desktop\Final Program\TestMaker.py", line 53, in <module>
    qs.AddQuestion(None, Question, Answer[1] , Answer[2], Answer[3], Answer[4], Answer[5])
TypeError: AddQuestion() takes 7 positional arguments but 8 were given
```

Seems easy enough to figure out. I just went through all of my query statements and counted seven positional arguments. Every time. Including the id. What is this black magic? I'm so lost, it's not even comical.

Here's all the code that generates a sqlite3 query.

```
def CreateDb(self):
    query = """CREATE TABLE Questions
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Question TEXT, Answer1 TEXT, Answer2 TEXT, Answer3 TEXT, Answer4 TEXT, CorrectAnswer TEXT)"""
    self.cursor.execute(query)
    self.connection.commit()

def AddQuestion(self, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, CorrectAnswer):
    self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO questions
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", [None, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, CorrectAnswer])
    self.connection.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qs = QuestionStorage(testName + ".db")
    qs.CreateDb()    
    qs.AddQuestion(None, Question, Answer[1] , Answer[2], Answer[3], Answer[4], Answer[5])
```

I'm so lost right now :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't require `None` (AFAICT):

```
qs.AddQuestion(None, Question, Answer[1] , Answer[2], Answer[3], Answer[4], Answer[5])
```

Also, you'll have problems later in your query in `.AddQuestion` - I count 8 in the following for the place holders...

```
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and 7 for the parameters... So, not sure what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 4):

`AddQuestion` is a bound method of an object (the object being `qs` in your case), not an unbound function. That means when you call it, `qs` is automatically passed as the first positional argument, before the ones that you pass explicitly. That's why methods are usually written with `self` as the first argument.

You need to change

```
qs.AddQuestion(None, Question, Answer[1] , Answer[2], Answer[3], Answer[4], Answer[5])
```

to

```
qs.AddQuestion(Question, Answer[1] , Answer[2], Answer[3], Answer[4], Answer[5])
```